# How to create extension using phpStorm 2018.2.5

Tags: extension

I want to create an simple extension.How can I do that using phpStorm? Please guide me with steps.

Comment: If you have a answer then tell me. Don't give negative votes directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can study about creating CiviCRM extensions here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/

You would need to use Civix to create extensions and can use PHPstorm as text editor to write code i guess.

Thanks